# Cuando ejecuto Python 2.7.10 en un windows server 2019 me salta un error y no se ejecuta

Tags: python, windows, windows-server

Ejecuto Python desde CMD y en otros Windows server si que funciona pero en 2019 no,

Necesito ayuda para saber como solventarlo.

[image: Error eventos windows server 2019]

Comment: Python 2.7.10 está ya en el olvido, no tiene soporte ni nada. Puede que el windows donde lo querés instalar sea tan nuevo que perdió compatibilidad con esa versión.

Comment: El problema es que si actualizo a la ultima versión de Python, los comandos que tengo configurados saltan error y no se por que si se supone que tiene que funcionar con cualquier versión de Python.

Comment: Creo que no te entendí bien (no se ni que es lo que usas), me explicarías un poquito editando la pregunta que es un comando y que errores salen por favor? Quizá, estamos enfrentando un [problema xy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY)

Comment: Perdón, tengo configurado un Bot que ejecuta y responde a los comandos enviados. en este caso responde cuando se le3 escribe algo, claro esta con la ultima versión de Python me salta un error en un archivo del Bot como si no reconociese la programación puesta, pero con versiones 2.7.xx si que lo reconoce correctamente, por eso no puedo poner una versión mas alta por que salta error en la programación del Bot

Comment: Python 2 y 3 tienen, por ejemplo, leves diferencias sintacticas. El código de Python 2 no siempre funciona bien en 3. Mi recomendación, es que actualizes el código de tu bot. Por que, si esto no es un problema de compatibilidad entre windows server 2019 y Python, entonces tarde o temprano te surgirá un problema de compatibilidad. Si insistes en no actualizar el código, la verdad no puedo ayudarte, ya que de windows server no se nada. Suerte!

Comment: Solucionado, El problema fue la versión, he puesto la 2.7.17 y ha funcionado, muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Acá no se marca una pregunta resuelta cambiando el título. Añade la respuesta en el campo de respuesta y unas horas después podrás marcarla como la respuesta aceptada. Incluso podrás recibir votos positivos. Revirtiendo la edición del título...